# Redeclaring LAUNCHER activity on android app - Splash added

Tags: android, manifest, launcher, splash-screen

I developed an app and decided to add a splash page. I created the class and added the activity to the manifest. I also moved the Intent tag to the new declaration and change the name but get a "Launcher not found" error on logcat.

My splash java file is called com.rarecreativegroup.dcm1config.splasher and my manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rarecreativegroup.dcm1config"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity android:name=".splasher" 
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            >
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
             >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".mySettings" 
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            >
            </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

to your intent-filter of the splasher-activity